# props.onTabChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently going through a tutorial on react native, but the code is out of date, so this is probably due to me trying to convert the legacy code into currently usable code.

I am attempting to implement a tab navigation system for a service status app, and the best I can come up with for the code in app.js is this:

```
_switchService(nextService) {
    this.setState({ selectedService: nextService })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} onServiceChange={this._switchService}>
        {this._renderTab(this.state.selectedService, this.state.services)}
        <TabBarContainer onTabChange={this.props.onServiceChange}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

And in a file called tabBarContainer.js:

```
const TabBarContainer = (props) => (
    <Tabs 
        style={styles.tabContainer}
        onSelect={comp => {
            props.onTabChange(comp.props.name)
        }}
    >
        <TabBarItem name="web" label="Web Server" icon="server" />
        <TabBarItem name="db" label="DB Server" icon="database" />
        <TabBarItem name="mail" label="Mail Server" icon="envelope" />
    </Tabs>
)

TabBarContainer.propTypes = {
    onTabChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

When I attempt to switch tabs using the following code, I get the above error for 'onTabChange.'  Now in the tutorial, he doesn't define onTabChange as a function anywhere, but it seems to work for him in the legacy code, but it looks like I have to define it somewhere here.  I'm just not sure where or how.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: It's basically saying `this.props.onServiceChange` is not a function, can you post your code for that?

Comment: you added `onServiceChange` to `View`. why did you do that?

Comment: @azium - The legacy code the tutorial uses still makes use of the old index.ios.js and index.ios.android files, and then creates a mainContainer.js to handle the display, whereas I built the app with the new version of react native, which uses a minimal index.js file and an app.js file.  I'm finding that most of what he puts in mainContainer.js for his version actually should go in app.js here, and so I'm forced to combine his index.ios.js and mainContainer.js code into app.js.  Given that, View was my best guess as to where onServiceChange should go using the new format, but I could be wrong.

Comment: sounds like you're doing a lot of guesswork. in any case from my cursory looking at your code you probably meant to say `onTabChange={this._switchService}` not `onTabChange={this.props.onServiceChange}`.

Comment: @MattAft He never explicitly defines onServiceChange as a function, which now that I look at it, strikes me as odd, but somehow in the legacy code, he gets it to work.

Comment: @azium - yes, that did the trick.  Thank you! :-)